# TypeError: t.fx is undefined when attempting to add jQuery-UI to Angular 4 app

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, typescript, npm

I am trying to add jQuery-UI to an application, as I need access to some sliders. I have installed the typings for jQuery with:

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

And what seem to be the jQuery-UI typings with

```
npm install @types/jqueryui --save
```

I have added the jQuery and jQuery-UI CDN references to the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SimutronApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in Firefox I get the error:

```
t.fx is undefined     jquery-ui.min.js:6
```

While Chrome throws:

```
cannot read property 'step' of undefined at <String>.anonymous
```

At the same line. Could anyone tell me the correct method for adding jQuery-UI to an Angular 4 project?

Comment: well i need answer too

Answer (score 32):

Jquery Slim removes some features that Jquery UI relies on.

Replace

```
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

With:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: t.fx is undefined